# Convert ERDAS Imagine AOI to Shapefile

Tags: erdas-imagine

I was trying to convert a very simple Erdas Imagine AOI file (its a single polygon) into a shapefile and was mostly finding documentation on the inverse (SHP to AOI). I was trying to follow the steps listed here, but keep getting the following "There are No Selected Elements". Below is a workflow that worked for me in case it is helpful for anyone else.

[image]

Comment: This video highlights how to accomplish the conversion: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EO6fFsuuPjg

Answer (score 2):

There might be an easier workflow, but this worked for me:

1. Open AOI (that you wish to convert to a shapefile) in 2D View (table of contents)
2. Create new shapefile (File > New > Vector Layer) Choose Polygon shape > OK
3. Select/Highlight AOI file in table of contents
4. Use Select tool (AOI tab > drawing tab) to select features from AOI you wish to copy
5. Click Copy icon (Vector Tab > Drawing > Copy)
6. Select/Highlight newly created shapefile
7. Select Paste from Selected Object icon (next to Paste)
8. Click continue on attention dialog box that pops up
9. Remove shapefile (right click in table on contents > Remove) and select to save changes.

Comment: What version are you using ?

Comment: @PROBERT, thanks, I'm using Erdas Imagine 2016

Comment: Yeah I have that the same thing @Iracambi ..what I would suggest you to create one in ArcGIS and then bring that in to ERDAS...but it looks like Keagen Allan just gave you a better way...

Answer (score 0):

With your polygon AOI already opened in IMAGINE.

Go to **File** tab -> **New Vector Layer** -> create a new shapefile layer

Select the new shapefile layer in the Contents window (the Contents list on left side)

Go to **Drawing** tab -> select **Enable Editing**

Reselect/highlight the AOI in the Contents window -> select **Copy**

Reselect the shapefile layer in the Contents window -> select "**PASTE FROM SELECTED OBJECT**" (it's the icon to the right of the "Paste" icon)

With the shapefile still selected, **Save** the new shapefile.